# Add Ads Admob in class and call from another Activity/Class

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-intent, admob

I want to add an **ads Interstitial** or **Banner** funtion in one class and access the same from some other class.

And I want to call it in all Activity classes

How can I achieve that?

```
package com.example....;
import ...


public class classAds{

private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;


public void mobileAds()
{
    MobileAds.initialize(this,
            "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713");

    mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-.............");

}
```

I tried this code but the problem in "this" is not accepted

I also tried to change it to

```
classAds.this
getContext()
getActivity()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am suggesting two methods

1.Create a separate Application class like this

```
public class ApplicationClass extends Application {

    private static ApplicationClass mInstance;

    public static Context getContext() {
        return mInstance;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mInstance = this;
    }

}
```

And then change your ClassAds like this

```
public class classAds{

private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;


public void mobileAds()
{
    MobileAds.initialize(ApplicationClass.getContext,
            "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713");

    mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(ApplicationClass.getContext);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-.............");

}
```

2. Change the ClassAds to

   ```
   public class classAds{

   private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;

   public void mobileAds(Activity activity)
   {
       MobileAds.initialize(activity,
               "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713");

       mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(activity);
       mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-.............");

      }
   ```

And in your Activity class call the method as

```
ClassAds classAds = new ClassAds;
classAds.mobileAds(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple case of missing the `context' required while creating the`InterstitialAd ` object.

There is one thing you can do, pretty simple and understandable.
Here is your code in a generic manner.

```
public class ClassAds{

private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
private Context mContext;

public ClassAds(Context context){
  //this is the constructor of this class
  mContext = context;
}
public InterstitialAd getMobileAds(){


    mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(mContext);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-.............");
    return mInterstitialAd;

   }
```

also as per documentation create a version of your own Application class and initialize the SDK only once per app launch. Read [docs](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/MobileAds#initialize(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String))

TO create your own application read [Here](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Understanding-the-Android-Application-Class)

make a final String variable with your SDK id  like this in Aplication class

```
private static final String _ad_id = "YOUR_ADMOB_APP_ID";
```

then initialize the SDK like this in the `onCreate` of Application class.

```
@Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
            MobileAds.initialize(activity, _ad_id );
    }
```

then from any activity or class use it like this.

```
ClassAds adsObject = new ClassAds(this)//here this is the context Activity
adsObject.getMobileAds();
```

Although you make this class singleton and utilize it in multiple Activities if **AdUnitId** remains same. Explore the possibilities!

Just if you missed, I guess you certainly didnot, [here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/InterstitialAd) is the official guide fro Ad loading.

Answer (score 0):

**Just issue is Context!
you pass the  context in Class contructor like that.
check below code!**

```
public class Interstial_Ads {

    private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
     Context context;


    public Interstial_Ads(final Context context) {
        this.context = context;

        MobileAds.initialize(context, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
               @Override
               public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {
                   mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(context);
                   mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712");
                   mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
                   if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()){
                       mInterstitialAd.show();
                   }

               }
           });

    }

}
```

> In the activity call that class passing acivity context.

```
Interstial_Ads         interstialAds = new Interstial_Ads(MainActivity.this);
```